# Aggregate data by date in java stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have a List of `StatisticsItem` (`String context, Integer numberOfHits, String yyyyMM`).
An example of instance is `context=WEBSITE, numberOfHits=12456, yyyyMM="2019-06"`.

I want to get a sorted `Map<String, Integer>` which has as key the yyyyMM date and as value the aggregated number of hits for this month.

I try this kind of code but I can't fill the blanks :

```
Map<String, Integer> collect = 
      list.stream()
          .sorted((s1, s2) -> s1.getYearAndMonth().compareTo(s2.getYearAndMonth()))
          ./* TODO: What method ? */((s1, s2) -> s1.getYearAndMonth().equals(s2.getYearAndMonth())
            ? new StatisticsItem(s1.getNumberOfHits() + s2.getNumberOfHits(), s1.getYearAndMonth()) // Construct new StatistictsItem without "context"
            : /* TODO: don't touch data with different dates */)
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(s -> s.getYearAndMonth(), s -> s.getNumberOfHits()));
```

Input :

```
{context="WEBSITE", numberOfHits=500, yyyyMM="2019-04", 
context="WEBSITE", numberOfHits=750, yyyyMM="2019-05", 
context="WEBSITE", numberOfHits=470, yyyyMM="2019-06",
context="REST", numberOfHits=5400, yyyyMM="2019-04", 
context="REST", numberOfHits=4700, yyyyMM="2019-05", 
context="REST", numberOfHits=9700, yyyyMM="2019-06"}
```

Desired output (context can be null or whatever else in this case) :

```
{context=null, numberOfHits=5900, yyyyMM="2019-04", 
context=null, numberOfHits=5450, yyyyMM="2019-05", 
context=null, numberOfHits=10170, yyyyMM="2019-06"}
```

Comment: `list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(StatisticsItem::getYearAndMonth, TreeMap::new, Collectors.summingInt(StatisticsItem::getNumberOfHits)))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just group by the date field.

```
list.stream().groupingBy(StatisticsItem::getYyyyMM, 
              Collectors.mapping(StatisticsItem::getNumberOfHits, Collectors.summingInt(Integer::intValue)))
```

Then you have a `Map<String, Integer>` with [yyyyMM - count] entries.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you really need a `Collection<StatisticsItem>` that are aggregated, so something like:

```
list.stream()
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         StatisticsItem::getYearAndMonth,
         Function.identity(),
         (left, right) -> {
              left.setNumberOfHits(left.getNumberOfHits() + right.getNumberOfHits());
              // map context how you want
              return left;
         }
     )
 )
 .values()
```

The idea is that you can merge ( `left` and `right` ) in the sample above how you want them to be merged when there are two instances (or more) having the same `yearAndMonth`

Comment: It should be noted that this would change (some of) the original `StatisticItem`s though.

Comment: @daniu right, the merging, of course can be done with creating a new instance

Comment: @daniu and the indeterminism regarding which will be changed and how (except for those being in the final map).